# How to deploy debug DLLs to another machine?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to remotely debug an application.  The application is complaining that debug DLLs are missing.

Going to the MS site [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx), it says that there are 3 ways to do this:

> There are three ways to deploy debug versions of Visual C++ library DLLs together with the debug version of an application.
>
> 1. Use central deployment to install a debug version of a particular Visual C++ DLL to the `%windir%\system32\` directory by using a Setup project that includes merge modules for the right library version and architecture of your application. Merge modules are found in the `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` directory in `\Common Files\Merge Modules\`. The debug version of a merge module has Debug in the namefor example, Microsoft_VC110_DebugCRT_x86.msm. An example of this deployment may be found in [Walkthrough: Deploying a Visual C++ Application By Using a Setup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293568.aspx).
> 2. Use local deployment to install a debug version of a particular Visual C++ DLL in the application’s installation directory by using files that are provided in the `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` directory in `\Microsoft Visual Studio <version>\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\`.
>
> Note
>
> For remote debugging of your application built by using Visual C++ 2005 or Visual C++ 2008 on another computer, you have to deploy debug versions of Visual C++ library DLLs as shared side-by-side assemblies. You can use either a Setup project or Windows Installer to install corresponding merge modules.
>
> 3. Use the **_Deploy** option in the **Configuration Manager** dialog box in Visual Studio to copy the project output and other files to the remote computer. An example of this deployment may be found in Set Up Remote Debugging for a Visual Studio Project.

Point 1 seems to require some licence which I don't have.  Point 2 doesn't have the MBCS debug files.  Point 3 the Configuration Manager's Deploy column is all greyed out.

This is quite frustrating.  Shouldn't be so difficult. :(  Any ideas how to pull over all the required DLLs?  I have tried to do this one at a time, with the application failing and telling me which DLL that is missing, but this didn't work.  I am now stuck at a `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library` error window that just states `abort() has been called`.

## Update

The last error that I had was related to our application requiring registration of some COM components.  After this was done, it worked fine.

Comment: Compile the DLLs in debug mode, and make sure the PDB files are in the same directory.\

Comment: @rory.ap, I'm sharing the directory so that I'm guaranteed that all files are there.  I've even tried to copy over the entire compile directory without joy.

Comment: It is a bit convoluted because VS2005/8 used the side-by-side cache.  That's all gone, simply copying the DLLs in the same directory as the EXE is enough.  Second bullet is easiest, just copy them from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist directory.  But MBCS is different, sigh why did you, you'll have to dig that one up.  Probably from c:\windows\syswow64 for the 32-bit version.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, I had already found them there and copied them over.  But that wasn't the issue.  Seems that we have come COM components that weren't being registered.  Finally registered them and now it works.  _sigh_

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to do a piecemeal:

1. Run application
2. If get error message

   2. a. Find and copy over the file from `%windir%\sysWOW64`
   3. b. Close error message window
   4. c. Go to step 1
3. Success!